# Errors after converting a Rails application to use Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I was using prototype with Rails 3 but i converted to jquery using:

```
rake rails:template LOCATION=http://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery/raw/master/jquery.rb
```

as suggested here https://github.com/lleger/Rails-3-jQuery

But after the conversion all the javascript seems broken
I am getting errors like:

RJS error:

> ReferenceError: $$ is not defined

AND then

```
$$("#notice").each(function(value, index) {
value.hide();
});
Element.update("cart", "<div class=\"cart_title\">Your Cart</div>\n<table>\n  <tr id=\"current_item\">\n  <td>3&times;</td>\n  <td>Programming Ruby 1.9</td>\n  <td class=\"item_price\">$148.50</td>\n</tr>\n\n\n  <tr class=\"total_line\">\n    <td colspan=\"2\">Total</td>\n    <td class=\"total_cell\">$148.50</td>\n  </tr>\n\n</table>\n<!-- START_HIGHLIGHT -->\n<form method=\"get\" action=\"/orders/new\"  class=\"button_to\"><div><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Checkout\" /></div></form>\n<!-- END_HIGHLIGHT -->\n<form method=\"post\" action=\"/carts/9\"  class=\"button_to\"><div><input name=\"_method\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"delete\" /><input data-confirm=\"Are you sure?\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Empty cart\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"6rsfHAqN1+p/Hb5/9QNxSFpXqmknSuUG2QtglirA6UM=\" /></div></form>\n");
$("current_item").visualEffect("highlight", {"startcolor":"#88ff88","endcolor":"#114411"})

;
```

What can be the possible problem?

The problem I think is that the helpers which use scriptaculous get broken. Rails 3 helpers are using scriptaculous. What is the way out is the bigger question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors refer to functions that Prototype provides, but which jQuery doesn't. Simply put you still have javascript code that uses Prototype, which is now no longer provided, hence the errors.

Comment: Yes, I got that.Scriptaculous effects which need prototype got broken. But Rails 3 helpers are using them. How to get that fixed?

Comment: @Arkid - "The core problem for Rails developers who might like to try out jQuery is that it eventually conflicts with the prototype library when you start to use Rail’s “in-built” helpers for prototype.

But perhaps you do not need to use these helpers, as an increasing number of jQuery plugins start to provide more and more elegant client-side functionality." -- http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/08/23/ajax-on-rails-prototype-vs-jquery/